# passing array of elements to a jquery / javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to make a calendar with html and jquery / javascript. In this calendar, I am trying to show the dates dynamically in a row of divs with a given class, floated inside another div.

the HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="view-month">

    <div class="day">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    ......an array of 42 elements for a 7 x 6 grid for viewing a month
    <div class="day">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="day">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

the jquery i am trying is as follows :

```
        $(document).ready(  function() { 

        var date = new Date(); // Gets the current date in a variable
        var selected_date = date.getDate(); // gets the current date (only dd)
        var month_no = date.getMonth(); // Gets the month as number - like January : 0, February : 1, March : 2
        var year = date.getFullYear(); // Gets the year in 'yyyy' format
        var month_string; // variable for holding the no. of days in the selected month
        var no_of_days_in_month; // variable for holding the total no. of days in the selected month for the selected year

        // ******** The following array holds the names of all the months for showing the chose month ********* //
        var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

        $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year); // shows the month in the heading of the calendar on month-name, 'yyyy' format


        // ******** code for showing dates of the selected month and year showing in the header ********//

        //function monthDetail(month_string) { }

        if (month_string == 'January') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 0;
        }

        if (month_string == 'February') {

            var isleapyear = function(year) {
                return (yr % 400) ? ((yr % 100) ? ((yr % 4) ? false : true) : false) : true;
            }

            if (isleapyear) {
                var no_of_days_in_month = 29;
            }

            else {
                var no_of_days_in_month = 28;
            }
            month_no = 1;
        }

        if (month_string == 'March') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 2;
        }

        if (month_string == 'April') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 30;
            month_no = 3;
        }

        if (month_string == 'May') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 4;
        }

        if (month_string == 'June') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 30;
            month_no = 5;
        }

        if (month_string == 'July') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 30;
            month_no = 6;
        }

        if (month_string == 'August') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 7;
        }

        if (month_string == 'September') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 30;
            month_no = 8;
        }

        if (month_string == 'October') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 9;
        }

        if (month_string == 'November') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 30;
            month_no = 10;
        }

        if (month_string == 'December') {
            var no_of_days_in_month = 31;
            month_no = 11;
        }

        var alldivs = $('.day');  // the entire predfined array of divs with a given number (42, in the present case)
                                  // (for a calendar - will be depending on the design of the grid for the month-view ) 
                                  // is assigned to a variable


            // ********* the following function draws / shows the calendar for the chosen month and year *********** //

            function showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs) { 

                // ************** Get the first day of the month showing on the top pane **************//

                var FirstDayofMonth = new Date(year, month_no, 1); // returns the first day of the given month in long date format 
                                                               // showing the day of the week, date, month, year and time

                // ************** Get the first day of the first week of the month showing on the top pane **************//

                var FirstDayofFirstWeek = FirstDayofMonth.getDay(); // returns the number place of the first day of the month
                                                                // within 0 to 6 i.e. 7 days of week

                var ofset; // this variable holds the number of divs to be left free from top left while showing the month selected

                ofset = FirstDayofFirstWeek;

                var no_of_div; // no of divs to be highlighted as days of the month in concern

                no_of_div = no_of_days_in_month;



                // **** the following variable holds the no of divs from the first div in the matrix of the calendar to the div 
                // **** showing the last date of the month in concern **** //

                var divcount = parseInt(ofset)+parseInt(no_of_div); //without parseInt() it will produce garbage and hence ridiculously wrong result


                var i; //index for looping over the entire array of divs ( the entire grid for a calendar)  

                var j = 1; //for counting date of a calendar



                for (i = 0; i <= divcount-1; i++) {

                        if (i >= ofset && i <= divcount) {

                            $(alldivs[i]).html(j).css({'background-color':'#ff7'});

                                if (j == selected_date) {

                                    $(alldivs[i]).html(j).css({'background-color':'#def'});

                                }

                        j++;}
                    }

                } // end of function showCalendar()


        // ******************* end of function showCalendar() ********************** //


        showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs);

        // ******** code to show calendar in the grid ******** //

        $('#go-to-previous-year').on('click', function() {
            year = year - 1;
            $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);
            showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );
        });

        $('#go-to-next-year').on('click', function() {
            year = year + 1;
            $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);
            showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );
        });

        $('#go-to-previous-month').on('click', function() {

            if (month_no == 0) { 
                month_no = 12;
                month_no = month_no - 1;
                $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);
                month_string = months[month_no];
                showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );
            }
             else {
                month_no = month_no - 1;
                $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);
                month_string = months[month_no];
                showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );
            }
        });

        $('#go-to-next-month').on('click', function() {
            if (month_no == 11) { 
                month_no = -1;
                month_no = month_no + 1;
                $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);
                month_string = months[month_no];
                showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );
            }
            else {
                month_no = month_no + 1;
                $('#month-and-year').html(months[month_no] + ', ' + year);  
                month_string = months[month_no];
                showCalendar(year, month_no, selected_date, alldivs );              
            }

        });

        }); //end of $(document).ready()
```

I guess, I am not passing the array of the 42 divs with class 'day' properly (which I have been trying to do by means of the variable 'alldivs' here) and hence the calendar is not showing. There is no error message from the function.

The same code works when I run it separately - i.e. without putting it inside a function. So my guess is that I have to pass the array of these 42 divs to the function as parameter and change their attributes and html to show the calendar.

Can anyone help?

Regards

Sukalyan

Comment: My first question is, are you intentionally redeclaring no_of_days_in_month each time you assign a value to it? Because you have it declared at the top and redeclared throughout.

Comment: well that can be done away with .... yes. mistake in hurry due to cut and paste

Comment: don't you mean `if(isleapyear(year))` instead?

Comment: well that can be done as well

Comment: ... but guys ...... what is important is the function for showing the calendar in the grid .... !!

Comment: For what you are creating a calendar. You can use any calendar plugins?

Comment: Did you try setting `month_string` as described in my answer? It shows your calendar for me.

Comment: The reason that these things we are mentioning are important is because they may be what is causing the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`month_string` is not set anywhere, so `no_of_days_in_month` never gets set, so everything falls over.

Fixing those I at least get a big yellow box with 1-31 down the page and 16 (today) highlighted, instead of a blank page. I am not sure if that's what the final result should look like but it is a step forward.